# Using multiprocessing Pool for expandable lists

Tags: python, multithreading, producer-consumer

I am trying to implement a producer-consumer solution for an external sorting problem. I have three binaries which breaks the file, sorts a file and a binary which merge two files. Here's my multiprocessing Pool implementation for sorting:

```
files = [a list of files generated after running splitter binary]

pool = Pool(args["numthreads"])
pool.map(sort_file, files)

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Here's my sort_file function:

```
def sort_file(file):
    cmd = ["./file_sort"] + [file]
    print('executing: %s')%' '.join(cmd)
    subprocess.call(cmd)
```

This is working as expected but I am not able to make similar pattern work for merge_files function which consumes two files from the list make a new file and that file should be appended back to list. My merge_file code looks like this:

```
def merge_file(file1, file2):
    cmd = ["./merger"] + [file1, file2]
    out, err, ecode = execute_commands(cmd)
    next_file.put(out)  #This is the merged file which will be appended back to list
```